# Socket Programming

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

In simulation of a lan-messenger in c# I am using the loopback address just for starters to check the functionality of the code.However after sending a few messages, I am getting a socket exception while using the end-connect method and then a socket exception while sending the data. Is there any reason behind this exception.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HideCaret(this.textBox1.Handle);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.textBox1.Text);
        str = this.textBox2.Text;
        Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,socketType.Stream,   ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(localaddress, 5555);
        newsock.BeginConnect(ip, new AsyncCallback(connected), newsock);
        if (str != "")
        {
            sb.AppendLine(this.textBox2.Text);
            this.textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            this.textBox2.Text = "\0";
            send = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
            try
            {
                newsock.BeginSend(send, 0, send.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sent), newsock);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("arguments incorrect in begin-send call", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error in accessing socket while sending", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("socket closed while sending", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error while sending", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

        }                                 

    }
```

Please help

Comment: General tip: in your exception handlers, incorporate the Exception.Message string into what you display, as it contains more specific information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possibly because you're not waiting for the socket to be connected before sending data. You have two options:

1. Send the data asynchronously from your `connected` callback method.
2. Send the data synchronously by blocking this thread until connected.

You accomplish #1 by combining the data to send and the socket into a new class, then passing that as `state` in your call to [`BeginConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6.aspx). Then move your send code to the callback method.

You accomplish #2 by setting up a [`System.Threading.ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and calling [`WaitOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx) after [`BeginConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6.aspx). Then call [`EndConnect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.endconnect.aspx) in your `connected` callback method, followed by a [`Set`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx) on your [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). Then proceed to send as you have above.

---

You'll also probably learn more if you find out what kind of `SocketException` you're getting.

From the MSDN Documentation:

> If you receive a `SocketException`,
>   use the `SocketException.ErrorCode`
>   property to obtain the specific error
>   code. After you have obtained this
>   code, refer to the Windows Sockets
>   version 2 API error code documentation
>   in the MSDN library for a detailed
>   description of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate thread reading from the socket? If not, your socket buffers are probably filling up.

Comment: I have made an asynchronous call for receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .Net `Socket.Connect` method it will block your code until connection. So, you don't need to use `ManualResetEvent` and calling `WaitOne`. And you can further use other socket asynchronous methods too.